# cypress: execute setup method once before starting a feature

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cypress

Have a requirement where before running the feature "abfeatureTest1" few initial data setup required for validation needs to be created through UI and is available in method "beforeFeatureTest1".
I need to execute the method "beforeFeatureTest1" only once before running the feature "abfeatureTest1" and discard the data after feature execution.

I am aware of After/Before all hooks and After/Before scenario hooks, But i need something like After/Before feature hook.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Hema - Why do you need to run initial data setup only once before running a feature? Can you please give an example? Reason for asking this is, your scenarios have to be independent and by running the test data setup only once before running the feature suggests that your scenarios are not autonomous

Answer (score 1):

For Cypress-Cucumber, following hooks will run before and after **each feature file** but **not after each scenario**

```
before(()=>{
    cy.log('======before=====')
})

after(()=>{
    cy.log('======after=====')
    cy.wait(5000)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have tags at FeatureFile level and at Scenario level.
[image]

So @FeatureFile3 tag will run all the cases in your FeatureFile3
and @FF1scenario2 tag will run only particular scenario

You can specify these tags in your runner class for execution as per your requirement.

```
@CucumberOptions(features= "src/main/resources/publish", tags="@FeatureFile3",  format = {"pretty"} )
```